# Code Tactic for values over muliple time intervals

Tags: amazon-redshift

Looking to simplify code and execute most effectively

I need to write SQL for reporting that has week-to-date, month-to-date, and year-to-date levels of the same data.  Which tactic would execute faster and be more simplistic:  Write sub-queries for each of the time periods or pull the lowest level of detail and use the partition over functionality within CASE statements?

Using POSTGRESQL 8.0 and AWS tables

I am leaning towards the sub queries tactic.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. As it stands, your question is likely to invite opinion and discussion, rather than answers - and that's off topic here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please post a specific question, and help us evaluate "effective" and "simple".